# laravel - 500 Internal Server Error - insert code error

Tags: php, laravel

I am a total newbie to laravel.
I try to insert data into db and get - 'NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error'.

This is my code -

```
class UserController extends BaseController {


    public function index() 
    {
        $user = new User;

        $user->username = 'tester';
        $user->password = md5('calpinet');
        $user->fullname = 'Tester';
        $user->email = 'tester@gmail.com';
        $user->status = 0;

        $user->save();
        return View::make('user.index');
    }
}
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('user/index', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('user/', 'UserController@index');
```

Can anyone help me , please...

Comment: Can you show us your routes and your template file?

Comment: check this, it might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23326799/laravel-4-saving-user-into-database-not-working

Comment: @Jerodev - index.php is just a static page.

Comment: `500` means *read your server logs*. What do your server logs say?

Comment: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: In your config.php file turn debug => true. Give you more info.

Comment: I am just guessing there is no AUTO INCREMENT flag on PRIMARY key in table

Comment: @James Elliott - Thanks. Fixed it. Its just 'Column not found' error. Laravel try to insert both updated and created date.

Answer (score -1):

Try running `composer install` after cloning the repo. The vendor directory is in the Laravel `.gitignore` file by default.